# UIScrollView updating troubles

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

So I have UIScrollView. I download img from web server and add subview to uiscrollview. I'm doing this asynchronious. It downloads pictures very well but it just doesn't display them. I need to tap on the screen and move a little bit and after that the pictures appears... Is it a way do display them by the code? thanks

```
myWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
customBtnWidth = myWidth  - 30;


NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: pictureUrl]];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

imgView.frame = CGRectMake( x*customBtnWidth, self.videoView.bounds.size.height ,customBtnWidth,customBtnWidth);
imgView.center = CGPointMake(15+ customBtnWidth /2 + x * customBtnWidth + x*30, customBtnWidth / 2);


[self.scrollView addSubview:imgView];
//
//[self.scrollView motionBegan:UIEventSubtypeNone withEvent:UIEventSubtypeNone];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.photosView.bounds.size.width+ number*customBtnWidth, customBtnWidth );
//[self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
//[self.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
[imageData release];
[img release];
[imgView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already tried `[self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];` but its commented out. Did that not work?

You can also try setting `scrollView's` `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw` like `self.scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;` while initializing the `scrollView` and check if that solves it.

Comment: [self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay]; it is not working self.scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;  it is not working too